# File upload via web request doesn't work

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I'm sorry about the title but at the moment I'm not creative enough to get a better one.

I'm trying to upload a file to xup.in (to provide a little API in C#). But somehow the request isn't a valid one. Either xup.in can read it nor Wireshark. The Post-Request is valid but the multipart form data isn't.

Request is sent by the following function:
http://pastebin.com/AvwzxCLA (Sorry but I can't use the code tag)

This is how I create the request: http://pastebin.com/btrg9xiZ

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What errors? Exceptions?

Comment: No errors. I just get a 301 back and wireshark can't read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark - the boundary string needs to have a leading `--`, and the last line of the message must have the form: `--boundarystring--`, otherwise the message is invalid. the [MIME Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) on Wikipedia contains a good example of what the message should look like. Dumping the request to a file and making sure that it is a valid multi-part message is a good start.

**Edit**

You should really use the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) framework, instead of the method you are using. It encapsulates all this functionality.

By altering your mime body construction, I was successfully able to upload from the script. Note, I removed the `Content-Type` from the parameters as it's not needed, plus I made sure that the boundaryString was properly formed i.e. the string that is passed in as `boundaryString` is the one that was used in the request header, without the leading `--`

I made the function perform double-duty - it calculates the size only if the Stream is `null`.

```
    public static long sendMultiPartReq(Stream req, string boundaryString, object[] files, object[] parameters)
    {
        String CRLF = "\r\n";
        byte[] b;
        long contentLength = 0;

        foreach (string[] file in files)
        {
            b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                CRLF + "--" + boundaryString + CRLF +
                String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"" + CRLF,
                    file[0], Path.GetFileName(file[1])) +
                "Content-Type: image/png" + CRLF + CRLF);
            contentLength += b.LongLength;
            if (req != null) req.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            if (File.Exists(file[1]))
            {
                b = File.ReadAllBytes(file[1]);
                contentLength += b.LongLength;
                if (req != null) req.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }
            b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CRLF);
            contentLength += b.LongLength;
            if (req != null) req.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
        foreach (string[] parameter in parameters)
        {
            b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                "--" + boundaryString + CRLF +
                String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"" + CRLF, parameter[0]) +
                CRLF + parameter[1] + CRLF);
            contentLength += b.LongLength;
            if (req != null) req.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
        b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundaryString + "--" + CRLF);
        contentLength += b.LongLength;
        if (req != null) req.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        return contentLength;
    }
```

Comment: Nice try I realy forgot the last boundary, but this isn't the error. The same problem anyway :(.
Updated Code: http://pastebin.com/AvwzxCLA